# Why is this cast in my generic Kotlin function unchecked?

Tags: kotlin, generics, casting

Take a look at this MVCE:

```
abstract class Bar

class BarHolder(val barFunctor : Bar.()-> Unit)

fun <T : Bar>foo(bar: T.() -> Unit) {
    val activeRequest = BarHolder(bar as (Bar.() -> Unit))
}
```

The cast `bar as (Bar.() -> Unit)` is marked as unchecked. But I can't think of a scenario where the cast fails at runtime, since `T` is always a subclass of `Bar`, isn't it?

I know I can ignore it by adding `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")` but this seems bad practice to me. So what is the right way to avoid the unsafe cast?

For more context, the intended use case looks similar to this:

```
class LongBar : Bar()
    val length = 69

fun foobar(){
    foo<LongBar>(){
        println(length)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's something to do with erasure.  But I don't have a solution, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not type-safe and Kotlin is correct it should not be allowed.

The problem is that you may have a consumer of a very specific type of `Bar`, for example `Bar1` and then you cast it to consumer of any `Bar` objects. What if you then use this consumer of `Bar1` and pass a `Bar2` object to it?

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val bar1Consumer: Bar1.() -> Unit = { toString() }
    val holder = foo(bar1Consumer)
    holder.barFunctor.invoke(Bar2()) // ClassCastException
}

fun <T : Bar>foo(bar: T.() -> Unit) = BarHolder(bar as (Bar.() -> Unit))

class Bar1 : Bar()
class Bar2 : Bar()
```

It is hard to relate to your real example as we don't know what exactly happens in `foo()`, but please note after that unchecked cast this is allowed and will throw the `ClassCastException`:

```kotlin
val activeRequest = BarHolder(bar as (Bar.() -> Unit))
activeRequest.barFunctor.invoke(IntBar())
```

Comment: It took me some time, but it makes sense now. My mistake was to look at the `foo` function in isolation and not consider the invoke part. Since the invoke part is at a completely different location in my program.

Comment: Is following explanation also make sense: since T is an subclass of Bar, then `bar: T.() -> Unit` could be a function defined in a subclass and not present in a Bar class. Therefore, you couldn't pass it as a `Bar.()-> Unit` because there could be no denoted by `bar` function in an object of a general class Bar.